# Any program to simulate electric motor performance?

Tags: power-electronics

Does anyone know any program that I can use to simulate the performance of an electric motor?
I'm trying to design one from scratch and I would need tools that don't make me spend a lot of money on experimental tests.

if anyone knows something they appreciate it very much

Comment: _"I'm trying to design one from scratch"_ - Why?

Comment: There is a lot of SW around... https://www.modelica.org/ , scilab , elmer , https://jupyter.org/ , ... All of them will require some work, [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_computer_simulation_software]

Comment: For a "generic" simulator / data processing many engineers use Matlab, it is paid software. There's a free alternative: GNU Octave. Do realize that any simulation can only be as good as the models it uses. If you "design your own" then any models you find elsewhere might not be accurate.

Comment: @BruceAbbott i would like to simulate some ideas before test this in real world.

Comment: You might look at FEMM since the design and performance of the magnetic circuit will be crucial. Don't know about Matlab but the Linux support link at http://www.femm.info/wiki/HomePage suggestt it interoperates with Octave so there's probably Matlab support too.

Comment: Are you trying to design the motor itself or the motor controller? What type of electric motor will you be designing or controlling? Applying only the [power-electronics] tag suggests that you are only investigating a power electronics circuit without regard to anything else.

Comment: _"i would like to simulate some ideas before test this in real world"_ - yes, that much is obvious. But why do you want to design a motor 'from scratch' rather than use or modify an existing design?